# how to use locale independent strtod with error reporting

Tags: c++, oop, std

I am using strtod() to convert string to decimal. Since I need to throw an error for incorrect input/invalid characters in i have no other choice. 
 However the problem is that strtod() is affected by locales. So a '.' becomes an invalid character when the program is run in a different locale

If I use a solution like this:

```
std::istringstream text(iterator->second.c_str());
text.imbue(std::locale::classic());
double result;
text >> result;
```

it is not possible to check for invalid input at all.

Which solution can provide me both?

Comment: _"i have no other choice"_ That's highly unlikely!

Comment: What is the reason behind you not wanting locale-aware conversion? What if someone with a system set to use the comma as decimal point tries to run your program, and expects the comma to work?

Comment: You could temporarily get the current locale, set it to the "C" locale, then set it back when you're done. Use RAII.

Comment: @PaulJ.Lucas Note that `setlocale` may change the locale for all threads in the process, not just the calling thread, so temporarily changing the locale like this is generally not possible using `setlocale`.  (Different implementations may behave differently here:  In the Microsoft implementation, the locale is global by default, but thread-local locale may be enabled via various options.  I don't know about other implementations except that the POSIX spec for `setlocale` says that "The locale state is common to all threads within a process.")

Comment: Yeah, well, the OP didn't specify whether his program is single or multi-threaded.

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg: the input values comes from an xml file. When the aplication is run in a different locale, the same xml files are used

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can determine if the value provided to the stringstream was completely converted or not.  You can test the stream to see if it reached the end of file.  If it has then you have read everything and converted it to a double.  If not then there was invalid input.

Here is a little sample demonstrating the conversion:

```
bool convert(const std::string & text)
{
    if (text = "")
        return false;
    std::istringstream iss(text);
    iss.imbue(std::locale::classic());
    double result;
    iss >> result;
    if (iss.eof())
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << convert("123.456") << std::endl;
    std::cout << convert("123.456abc") << std::endl;
    std::cout << convert("123.456e5") << std::endl;
    std::cout << convert("e5") << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
1
0
1
0
```

<kbd>[Live Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f9dd89be5be6e74c)</kbd>

Comment: @ecatmur I added handling for empty strings.  This was more a proof of concept but thanks.

Comment: @NathanOliver . thanks for the answer. nice use of eof.

Answer (score 0):

You can check for invalid input by testing `text` for errors and that it reached the end of input:

```
text >> result;
bool ok = text && text.eof();
```

Example: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/758b769f26567d1e